# How can I detect of which figure(circle, polygon) comes some events when this is overlaid it? google maps api javascript

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3, geometry, polygons

I have problems with geometry figures in google maps(circles and polygons), example: when i have two circles overlaid and I use the event mouse over or mouseout, google maps is only print the information of the circle more big , because the big figure is put after the small. i have the same problems if i have 7 circles or polygons almost in the same position.

This is a example with two circles, but the problem is in the combination of the figures.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 80%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

// This example creates circles on the map, representing populations in North
// America.

// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
var citymap = {
  chicago: {
    center: {lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629},
    population: 845837
  },
  chicago1: {
    center: {lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629},
    population: 2714856
  },
  losangeles: {
    center: {lat: 34.052, lng: -118.243},
    population: 3857799
  },
  vancouver: {
    center: {lat: 49.25, lng: -123.1},
    population: 603502
  }
};

function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: 37.090, lng: -95.712},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  var cont=0;
  for (var city in citymap) {
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      text:'hola'+cont,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      title:'hola'+cont,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      optimized: false,
      zIndex:10,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    });
    cont++;
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'mouseover', function(event) {
     var lat = this.getCenter().lat();
     var lon = this.getCenter().lng();
     var lat2 = event.latLng.lat();
     var lon2 = event.latLng.lng();
     console.log(lat+lon+"Circulo"+this.text);
     console.log(lat2+lon2+"mouse");
     console.log(this.zIndex+"index"+this.text);
 });
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle,'mouseout',function(event){
     var lat = this.getCenter().lat();
     var lon = this.getCenter().lng();
     var lat2 = event.latLng.lat();
     var lon2 = event.latLng.lng();
     console.log(lat+lon+"Circulo"+this.text);
     console.log(lat2+lon2+"mouse");
     console.log(this.zIndex+"index"+this.text);
    });
  }

}

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBwm19SMHtEZaXzloVeyMeMULkciJuatEo&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use mouseover/mouseout for that.  You need to process through all your objects and determine whether the mouseevent is inside the object or not (for a circle the distance from the center is less than the radius, for a polygon the `containsLocation` method).

Example `map` mousemove listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
  var lat = event.latLng.lat();
  var lon = event.latLng.lng();
  for (var i = 0; i < areaArray.length; i++) {
    if (areaArray[i].getRadius) {
      // circle
      if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(areaArray[i].getCenter(), event.latLng) < areaArray[i].getRadius()) {
      console.log("in circle:"+event.latLng.toUrlValue(6) + "Circulo center="+areaArray[i].getCenter().toUrlValue(6)+" radius="+areaArray[i].getRadius()+" meters, " + areaArray[i].text);
      // console.log(lat2 + lon2 + "mouse");
      // console.log(this.zIndex + "index" + this.text);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle (for the circles in your example)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0qg3Lwe1/)

Comment: Hi geocode, thank you very much, this can help me to my homework.